# Django: How to map <Select> options to database field values?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-models

Folks,

I am working on a legacy code where ChoiceField is rendered as follows and I can't change it because javascript uses all the values and labels:

```
<select>
<option value='one'>First</option>
<option value='second'>Second</option>
</select>
```

One the DB side, I have a field is of Integer type (1 = One, 2 = Two) to save it. Ideally the rendering should look like as follows:

```
<select>
<option value='1'>First</option>
<option value='2'>Second</option>
</select>
```

Now, I am try to map int and string choices by using Custom ChoiceField (by overriding ChoiceField) in the ModelForm. I am able to save data into the db but I am not able to render the values on the front-end side. I am not sure how to map these values to pass in as a value parameter of the render function of CustomSelectWidget.

Any inputs would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try to use a dictionnary

```
# Assuming "value" id the select value retrieved with request.POST.get
d = {
    'one': 1,
    'two': 2
}

if value in d:
    the_db_id = d[value]
else:
    # Error
```